# Laravel 5.3 - Register Controller

Tags: laravel

I have a question.. i create a new laravel project and do the auth::make. The login and the register worked and save the data from register in my local data base. But now i have a problem. **I have a custom controller (for example "myController.php) and inside this controller i have a function called "register"**. In my function i receive the Request $request and get the data (name, email and password) (I test and it worked, i receive the correct data in request). Now how is it possible to save this data in local database **using the Laravel Auth but using at the same time my controller and my function**?

Thanks ;)

Regards

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't clear enough for me. So do you want to hook your function after Register using *Laravel Auth*, don't you?

Comment: I want to use the Laravel Auth but using my register function and my controller. I want to use the features of laravel (Auth::check for example) and save the data in local database...The same that do the Auth Laravel but using my own function and controller

Comment: Thanks, i already solve my problem! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a new user manually in your own controller like Laravel does:

```
User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
    ]);
```

Comment: hi. Thanks for the reply. I have a question..i put this code inside my function in my controller? I dont need to change the routes files to create a post route to use my controller and my function? And i dont need to add my route in filed action on form register? thanks again

Comment: Redirect your login form request to: {{ url('/login') }} like this :
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
</form>

It will check if the user exists

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this into your register function:

```
User::create([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
]);
```

Comment: hi. I put this code in my function? thanks for the reply

Comment: Yes in your register function!

Comment: thanks :) my register functions works now :) I have other question.. i want to do the same to login. I have a login function in my controller that receive from request the email and password. Now how to check in local db if the email and password exists with Laravel Auth? If it exists i redirect to my dashboard view. Thanks again :)